# How do you write a Rails form that saves only changed items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, crud

I've got a form on which the user can edit many objects simultaneously. The form uses `form_tag`, and many instances (via iteration) of `text_field_tag`, `select_tag`, and `check_box_tag`.

As currently constituted, submitting the form causes the controller action to call `.save!` on every single object that might have been updated, regardless of whether the user made any changes to it. This is obviously not ideal.

How can I alter the form and controller action so that they only save the objects that need to be saved?

Comment: i use In "Place Editing gem", which works great, although i have not checked out the code to see if it saves everything when editing forms. Check it out https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place or the railscasts by ryan bates http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by setting up before_save filters on each of the corresponding models. Load the saved state of that current object, and compare the relative attributes. If none of the attributes changed, return false:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :check_for_changes

private
  def check_for_changes
    saved = Post.find(self.id)
    should_save = false
    if saved.body != self.body || saved.title != self.title
      should_save = true
    end
    should_save
  end
end
```

That said, i think the in place editing gem is a good idea. There may be another gem out there that does this as well. I'm just personally not aware of it.